# Proteins folds: relation to splicing and post-translational modification?

Tags: molecular-biology, proteins, protein-structure

Is the secondary structure pattern of protein folds related in any way to alternative splicing and post-translational modification?

Comment: "somehow related" is very vague - do you have some idea how they might be related?

Comment: Our prof.  in biochemistry basic seminary said, that diffrent kombinations of folds Is releted to diffrent function of protein. He didnt said anything that how Is this process regulated in Cell. So i thought that would be releted to alternative slicing. That one gene sliced to diffrent structure can have a simular pattern.

Comment: I see. So I don't think you mean 'secondary structure' - you probably mean domains. For example, see https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23562110 or this question https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/13834/what-are-some-examples-of-genes-that-code-for-multiple-proteins